# Spring Data Neo4j(Getting error "Cannot obtain single field value for field")

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am getting error:"Cannot obtain single field value for field 'creator'",so i am not getting it,why  it is coming.actually,when i create unique relationship,when i am fetching,then it is coming.I am using SDN with neo4j embedded.so,please help me to resolve it

my domain class

```
@NodeEntity
class CrowdFunding extends BaseEntity{
    String fundingFor
    String title

@RelatedTo(type="HAS_USER")
    User creator
}
```

my repository

```
@Query("Match (n:CrowdFunding) WHERE id(n)={0} match (user:User) where id(user) in {1} WITH n,user create unique (n)-[:HAS_USER {is_owner:false,is_contact_person:true,is_wishlist_crowdFunding:false,is_blacklist_crowdFunding:false}]->(user)")
    saveCrowdFundingContacts(long id,List contacts)
```

My controller

```
CrowdFunding crowdFunding = findOne(id,CrowdFunding.class)
```

Relationship created successfully,but when i fetch crowdfunding object using neo4j template method,then it is coming.

My config is :

```
org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.2.0.RELEASE
```

Comment: Also your create unique should only include the properties that you really want to be unique !! Otherwise you'll end up creating duplicate relationships too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query had probably created relationships to multiple `User` nodes from the same `CrowdFunding` node, since the query allows relationships to all `User` nodes with an ID in the `{1}` collection.

If this is indeed what you wanted, you would need to modify the `Crowdfunding` class to permit a collection of `Users`, like the following:

```
@NodeEntity
class CrowdFunding extends BaseEntity{
    String fundingFor
    String title

    @RelatedTo(type="HAS_USER")
    Collection<User> users
}
```